# TypeError: name() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not str

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Hi I am trying to use `unicodedata` in python 3.7 on Linux but unfortunately it fails. Any help is highly appreciated.

I was looking on the net for the same issue but I couldn't find any hint which points me on the right direction.

**My problem**: I make use of `unicodedata.name(string)` and there I get an error `TypeError: name() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not str`.

**Mininal working example**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import emoji
import unicodedata


def replace_emoji(document):
    emoji_all = emoji.EMOJI_ALIAS_UNICODE.items()
    emoji_items = []

    emoji_pattern = re.compile(u'|'.join(
        re.escape(u[1]) for u in emoji_all), flags=re.UNICODE)
    emoji_items = re.findall(emoji_pattern, document)

    for item in emoji_items:
        unicodes = []
        unicode_values = []

        for char in range(len(item)):
            if not len(item) > 1:
                unicodes.append(r'{:x}'.format(ord(item[char])).upper())

            unicode_values.append([hex(ord(x)) for x in item[char]][0])

        char_length = len(unicode_values)

        chars = [chr(int(u, 16)) for u in unicode_values]

        if char_length == 2:
            print(chars)

            value = u'\\U{:x}\\U{:x}'.format(
                ord(chars[0]), ord(chars[1])).upper()

            unicodedata.name(value)

    return document
```

**My test run**

```
print(replace_emoji(u''))
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: For what it's worth (it doesn't answer your question), in Python 3 `u'|' is '|'` and using `flags=re.UNICODE` is superfluous since strings are unicode to begin with.

Comment: @Johan Schiff my expected output is the name of the emoji like `HAMBURGER` when I use `print(replace_emoji(u'')` . Does this help to clarify the question?

Comment: thanks @Booboo I will change that, I am super new to python at all to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can treat all emoji chars as normal characters in python 3.

Can't test the code atm, but I think this should do it.

```
import emoji
import unicodedata


def replace_emojis(document):
    emoji_chars = emoji.EMOJI_ALIAS_UNICODE.values()

    def _emoji(char):
        if char in emoji_chars:
            return unicodedata.name(char)

    return ''.join(_emoji(char) or char for char in document)
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much this is exactly returning the expected output like `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER J` and `REGIONAL INDICATOR SYMBOL LETTER P`. I wonder if there is a name one name for the  flag or there are two like in the ouput.